# Fetching data using DOMDocument XPath Query in PHP

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I am trying to fetch data using dom document xpath query and I am facing some problem while fetching it.
Here is my html

```
<div class="abc">
<a href="xyz.php">
<span class="a1">Mexico</span>
<span class="a2">Canada</span>
<span class="a3">Brazil</span>
</a>
</div>
```

This is my html code. From this, I need to fetch the results in class `a1`,`a2`,`a3`.
For this I am writing like this.

```
$nodes = $xpath->query("//*[@class='abc']");
```

Can anyone help me in next step to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your HTML is broken. You close your `<a>` element twice.

Second, and with the first problem fixed, this isn't hard to do. You just need to search for `span` elements with the `class` attribute equal to one of those:

```
$nodes = $xpath->query("//*[@class='abc']//span[@class='a1' or @class='a2' or @class='a3']");
```

You *could* do `starts-with`:

```
$nodes = $xpath->query("//*[@class='abc']//span[starts-with(@class, 'a']");
```

Obviously, however, that would also match `apple` or `antelope` as well as `a1`. This may not be desirable behaviour.

Comment: This is not working for me, if I implement like this, I am getting DOMNodeList Object
(
    [length] => 0
) as zero. Plz check once

Comment: @GireeshRaju It's because you removed the first `</a>` whereas I presumed you would remove the second one! That meant that the `span` wasn't an immediate child of the `div`. If you use `//`, as in my updated answer, it will work fine, because this looks for all descendents, not just immediate children.

Comment: Finally, This script worked for me
    $nodes = $xpath->query("//*[@class='abc']/a/span[starts-with(@class,'a')]");

Thanks @lonesomeday. Done with your help